# Index was out of range. ReportViewer C#

Tags: c#, reportviewer

im new to c# and im trying to create a report..
i translated my code form vb and follow exactly the same step on making the report but im getting the 'Index out of range error' in C# but it works fine in VB..

heres my code

```
   private void frmInvoice_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources[0].Value = Globals.cart;
        this.reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

Globals.cart is a datatable and i made sure it has rows in it before loading the report form..

im getting the report data from a dataset which has a datatable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me8LJ.png)

this practice work in vb.. im really confuse why it wont work.. please enlighten me.. im so noob

Comment: Based on the message and code you show, it sure sounds like `DataSources` is empty. I.e. `DataSources[0]` is outside the range because there is not even one thing in the collection.

Comment: But Globals.cart has values..

Comment: Doesn't matter, you're trying to assign to an index that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the `reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources[0]` doesnt exist.

you can add it ussing `reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(Globals.cart);`

edit: to add it in this way, `Globals.cart` needs to be a datasourrce.

edit2: in clase is not a datasource

```
ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1"; 
reportDataSource.Value = Globals.cart;
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
```